# How to add selective js on the page load?

Tags: nodes

I have initialized four js files in .info file.Now on a single page if i want to load only two of .js files not all ,how can i do this?

Answer (score 6):

JS included in your theme's .info file will be loaded on every page, there's no option to make them conditional (that I know of).

If you have files that need to be conditionally loaded you should do so in your theme's template.php file (perhaps in a [`hook_preprocess_page()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7) function), and use [`drupal_add_js()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7):

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  if ($some_condition) {
    $path = drupal_get_path('theme', 'MYTHEME') . '/path/to/file.js';
    drupal_add_js($path);
  }
}
```